# keyBoard does not disappear on Tapping on Fb feed share button on iOS 5 device

Tags: javascript, ios, html, facebook-javascript-sdk

I m using HTML5 and JS to build the app.

In app i have `facebook` feature, after login to `facebook` when i use post to wall feature, the feed dialog comes and after entering the text when i tap on Share button the SoftKeyboard of iOS does not goes off. Same app when i run it on iOS 4 device it running properly, I tried to set focus to other element like other button of the app after getting the response of post to wall in the callback function but it did not work

Comment: I m also facing the same issue as ours ...plz help....

Answer (score 0):

I also was facing same issue but when I updated Phonegap1.7.0 the issue was resolved.